# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Default Value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have added a new column to a table in the database. Instead of changing the code to insert this new column I tried created this new column to have a default value on insert.

```
    ALTER TABLE myTableName
    ADD DateColumn SMALLDATETIME DEFAULT GetDate()
    DECLARE @Dates SMALLDATETIME
    SET @Dates =  GetDate()

     UPDATE myTableName
     SET DateColumn = @Dates
     ALTER COLUMN DateColumn SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL
```

The problem is I get this error above because there are 13  columns and the code which hasnt been touched in years only inserts 12 columns and they are not explicit (ex

```
Insert into table ColumnNames Values(values))
```

It is just the plain

```
  insert into table Values (xxx, xxx ,xxx)
```

How can I get the insert to ignore the new column and just have the new column insert default data each time a new row is added?

Comment: This SQL code looks to be more SQL Server not MySQL.. MySQL supports `DECLARE` but only in stored programs. Besides `SMALLDATETIME` is a SQL server type and `GETDATE` is a SQL server function..

Comment: What is the issue with updating the code?

Comment: Code is in production. I work around a bunch of idiots who dont want to touch anything that isn't broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to sound a bit radical, but you can do the following:

- Rename the table to a new name
- Create a view with the old name but without the new column

Voila!  The view will be updatable and the old code should work.

Note:  This problem would never have happened if the `insert` had an explicit list of columns.  You should work on fixing the code as well as working around the problem.

Comment: (I think) you can even have `on INSERT` / `ON UPDATE` triggers on the view, allowing you to insert a custom value on the underlying table.